# Facebook login cached result issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have use case that i need to get access token then request long lived access token. Below code achieve this use case but can't handle cached result.

```
FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected')
        //sends token to server and server request long lived token.
}, { scope: 'email,user_birthday' });
```

Server fails to request long lived token if user is logged out from the other tab. Because user is logged out and that short access token is invalidated but still [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) brings invalidated cached token. I haven't found any parameter on [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) for specifying not to cache result.

But [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) have parameter for not to cache result. So in this case, i pass second parameter as true to [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) for not to having cached result. So inside that method if user is not logged in i call [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to prompt user login dialog. In this case true parameter remove cache problem and below code works perfectly fine except for one case. [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) inside [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) is blocked by browsers.

How can i prevent browsers to not to block login dialog at below example or call [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) directly without having cached result ? If both is not possible so is there another alternative solution ?

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        //sends token to server and server request long lived token.
    } else {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected'){
              //sends token to server and server request long lived token.       
            }         
        }, { scope: 'email,user_birthday' });
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Just don’t call FB.login within the FB.getLoginStatus callback, but call it on click on a button or something … then the browser won’t block the popup.

Comment: I shared what is wrong happenning when i cal FB.login directly. It caches result.

Comment: You can still do FB.getLoginStatus _before_ … (if that’s even necessary, initializing the JS SDK with `status: true` should accomplish the same thing).

Comment: FB.getLoginStatus with second true parameter and FB.login will cause 2 request to facebook servers and these async requests will not be ordered and this can cause unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Then only _display_ the button that calls FB.login after FB.getLoginStatus has returned … Btw., have you at least _tried_ it with the init parameter …?

Comment: init parameter with status : true is not what i want because after init result is cached and FB.login will not request fresh token. What i want is simply to call FB.login without having cached result.

Comment: Caching is in place for a reason; and your use case is everything else but typical – normally a user that wants to grant an app access would not log out in another tab in the meantime, don’t you think? So why is it so important to catch this edge case? Just let it fail, and if it does, alert the user to that fact and tell them they have to login in again.

Comment: @CBroe Facebook haven't provide a solution for this edge case. As you said if i fail to request long lived token because user is logged out already then i notify user with error and i call getLoginStatus with true parameter for refresh cached result.